# Comparisons of Oracle DATE column with java.sql.timestamp via JOOQ

Tags: oracle, date, jooq

I am using jooq to build queries for Oracle. Everything works fine except for dates:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    java.sql.Timestamp now = new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(... , ... , ...);
    final Factory create = new OracleFactory(con);
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    s.execute("create table test_table ( test_column DATE )");
    s.execute("insert into test_table values (to_date('20111111', 'yyyymmdd'))");

    // -- using to_date
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select count(1) from test_table where test_column<to_date('20121212', 'yyyymmdd')");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(""+rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();     

    // -- using a preparedstatement with java.sql.timestamp
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select count(1) from test_table where test_column<?");
    ps.setTimestamp(1,now);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(""+rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();

    // -- using jooq with java.sql.timestamp
    final org.jooq.Table<org.jooq.Record> table = create.tableByName("TEST_TABLE");
    final org.jooq.SelectSelectStep sss = create.select(create.count());
    final org.jooq.SelectJoinStep sjs = sss.from(table);
    final org.jooq.SelectConditionStep scs = sjs.where(create.fieldByName("TEST_COLUMN").lessThan(now));
    System.out.println(scs.toString());
    rs = s.executeQuery(scs.toString());
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(""+rs.getInt(1));
    rs.close();

    s.close();

}
```

Gives the following output:

```
   1
   1
   select count(*) from "TEST_TABLE" where "TEST_COLUMN" < '2012-12-12 19:42:34.957'
   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

I would have thought that JOOQ would check the type of Object in lessThan(Object)
to determine whether it can come up with a reasonable conversion, but apparently it
just does an Object.toString() in this case. I also remember that I never had issues with date queries via JOOQ in MySQL (although this is a while back). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this issue is due to the fact that `create.fieldByName()` doesn't know the type of the column (hence, Object), and coerces that unknown type on the right hand side of the comparison predicate. That should be fixed in jOOQ. I have registered #2007 for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2007

In the mean time, try explicitly setting the type on your field:

```java
create.fieldByName(Timestamp.class, "TEST_COLUMN").lessThan(now)
```